# Updating the record in two Active Record Callbacks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, callback, ruby-on-rails-5.1

Ok, stumbled upon this weirdness. I have this in my user model.

```
after_create :assign_role, :subscribe_to_basic_plan

  def assign_role
    self.role = 1
    self.save
  end

  def subscribe_to_basic_plan
    self.customer_id = "hello"
    self.save
  end
```

(code is simplified for illustration purposes)

When I create my user and check it in the console I get `role: 1, customer_id: nil`. But!, if I remove saving from the first callback everything works fine.

```
  after_create :assign_role, :subscribe_to_basic_plan

  def assign_role
    self.role = 1
  end

  def subscribe_to_basic_plan
    self.customer_id = "hello"
    self.save
  end
```

produces `role: 1, customer_id: "hello"`. So seems like it only reads the first `.save` in the callbacks. I would like to understand what is the exact behaviour and why. I spent a lot of time trying to pinpoint this and wouldn't want to stumble on something similar again.

EDIT:

Maybe this is helpful. When I use self.save! in `subscribe_to_basic_plan` I get an error and the record is not saved at all. Putting `self.save!` in the assign_role doesn't change anything, so the problem is definitely with the second `.save`.

Comment: What model validations do you have?

Comment: I am using devise with `:validatable` option. Nothing beyond that. So basic email and password validation

Answer (score 1):

This answer is theoretical since I'd need to see the full model code to be sure.

Most likely your first save in assign_role is failing for some reason. When it fails and returns falls that causes rails to skip all callbacks after it. Then your second callback never runs at all.

Possible solutions in my preferred order:

- Don't use callbacks. Have your controller set those values before you save the model.
- Use before_create so you aren't doing 3 saves of the exact same model in a row.
- Combine your two callbacks into one callback with only one save.
- Save using save(validate: false) in case it is failing on validation.

Comment: The problem doesn't seem to be in the first save, it succeeds fine, and when using `save!` doesn't throw errors. I think you are right in that something is fishy going on with validation. replacing with `before_create` and removing all saves worked, and probably the correct approach anyway. Since the question is more theoretical and asks why this is happening I'll leave it open for now.